# If $d$ is a metric in $X$ and $A \subset X$, does $\lvert d(x,A) - d(y,A) \rvert \le d(x,y) \phantom{5} \forall x, y \in X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, metric-spaces, vectors, triangle-inequality

I´m trying to prove that if  $d$ is a metric in $X$ and $A \subset X$, then:

$$
\lvert d(x,A) - d(y,A) \rvert \le d(x,y), \phantom{5} \forall x, y \in X
$$

The question seems very simple but I´m having problems to solve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2719411/42969 or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48850/42969.

Comment: Well, just to give you an idea, first use triangular inequality for $d(x, z)$, $d(y, z)$ and $d(x, y)$ for every $z$ in $A$. Next, use the fact that $|\int f(x){\rm d} x|\leq \int |f(x)|{\rm d} x$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continuity of the function $x\mapsto d(x,A)$ on a metric space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48850/continuity-of-the-function-x-mapsto-dx-a-on-a-metric-space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By symmetry, you just need to prove for one side that $d(x,A)-d(y,A)\leq d(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$. Pick $a\in A\subset X$, by triangle inequality, you get $$d(x,a)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,a)$$
Then take $\inf_{a\in A}$ on both sides, you get $$d(x,A)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,A)$$ By reordering, you get the inequality. This is a trick for this question, and I think you can figure this out why it works. Another side is similar, so I omit the proof.